# How to create object of derived class inside base class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a code like this:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def new_obj(self):
        return Base()  # ← return Derived()

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

In the line with a comment I actually want not exactly the `Derived` object, but any object of class that `self` really is.

Here is a real-life example from [Mercurial](https://selenic.com/hg/file/ff0d3b6b287f/mercurial/manifest.py#l935).

How to do that?

Comment: Clarification request: who will call this method? If you intend to call it _from_ the derived class, you can do this with a class method.

Comment: In your example, why would you call `Derived.new_obj()` as opposed to `Derived()`?. Also `new_obj` should be a `@classmethod` as others have pointed out in their answers.

Comment: @abyss.7 your example from Mercurial has a hard coded class name of `manifest`. It isn't the same. You can use `self.__class__` to get the class name of the current instance dynamically.

Comment: @JoshJ That is exactly what I want to replace it with. It shouldn't be hardcoded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of a really good reason to do this, *but* as D.Shawley pointed out:

```
def new_obj(self):
    return self.__class__()
```

will do it.

That's because when calling a method on a derived class, if it doesn't exist on that class, it will use the method resolution order to figure out which method to call on its inheritance chain. In this case, you've only got one, so it's going to call `Base.new_obj` and pass in the instance as the first argument (i.e. self).

All instances have a `__class__` attribute, that refers to the class that they are an instance of. So given

```
 class Base:
     def new_obj(self):
          return self.__class__()

 class Derived(Base): pass

 derived = Derived()
```

The following lines are functionally equivalent:

```
 derived.new_obj()
 # or
 Base.new_obj(derived)
```

You may have encountered a relative of this if you've either forgotten to add the `self` parameter to your function declaration, or not provided enough arguments to a function and seen a stack trace that looks like this:

```
>>> f.bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: "*I can't think of a really good reason to do this, but* ..." Encapsulation of mathematical and bitwise operator overloading result (return new derived class instance instead of instance variable operation result itself, without having to redefine overloading on inheritance). `obj3 = obj1 + obj2`

Answer (score 9):

```
def new_obj(self):
    return self.__class__()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a classmethod:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def new_obj(cls):
        return cls()

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

>>> b = Base()
>>> b.new_obj()
<__main__.Base at 0x10fc12208>
>>> d = Derived()
>>> d.new_obj()
<__main__.Derived at 0x10fdfce80>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a class method, which you create with a decorator.

```
In [1]: class Base:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def new_obj(cls):
   ...:         return cls()
   ...:

In [2]: class Derived(Base): pass

In [3]: print type(Base.new_obj())
<type 'instance'>

In [4]: print Base.new_obj().__class__
__main__.Base

In [5]: print Derived.new_obj().__class__
__main__.Derived
```

Incidentally (you may know this), you don't have to create `__init__` methods if you don't do anything with them.

Comment: But `__init__` methods will be called on object instantiating, nop?

Comment: @IronFist There are defaults automatically provided for you. They don't do much, but neither does defining an `__init__` that takes no args and just `pass`es :)

Comment: yea...just to give to the OP correct idea about the point of having `__init___` .. ;)